# Parsing blocks of data using schemas in Python

Tags: python, schema

I'm looking at developing a Python program that parses a data file.  The data in the file is stored in blocks of varying size, but it follows a regular format - the first bytes describe the length, the next describes the block's "object type", and the remainder describe specific characteristics of the object.

Given that I have over 120 different types objects, each with a unique layout, I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to go at processing those blocks rather than writing custom code for each type.  Given foreknowledge of the layout of each type, I suppose I could write an XML file or something that perhaps contains all of the specific layout information.

That said, I figured this sort of thing has been encountered before and someone probably has a much better way of tackling a problem like that.  given my general lack of expertise in Python, I thought I'd ask around first before I start banging out code...

Comment: I've written a package called `fixedrec` which is at PyPi (http://pythonhosted.org/fixedrec/). The `Layout` and `Record` classes might do what you need..?

Comment: Not quite, I'm afraid.  The block size varies, with the size indicated in the first few bytes.  So, I had an idea that it would be a matter of determining the object type on-the-fly and selecting an appropriate schema to load the data correctly.

Comment: The `Layout` class is a "schema", which maps from an array of bytes to typed fields (and back).  You'll need to switch on your type field, but `Layout` would probably make it easier to read/write each record type.  The `Layout` specification is pretty concise too so it should be faster to write (and easier to read) than a set of xml schema files. It doesn't do any type checking besides what the `struct` module does though..

Comment: That looks like a good solution really.  But it appears to me the block size is fixed from the opening of the file, and each block I read would likely have a different length...

Comment: That is true for the `RecordFile` class - you'll have to write the record navigation logic yourself. I was more thinking of utility functionality to read and parse record data once you'd arrived at the record. `r = MyRecordSubclass(my_layout, data=fp.read(len(my_layout))` will read the correct number of bytes and create an object with accessors - assuming the file pointer is correctly positioned - the fp will be positioned at the beginning of the next record when done.  If you're reading the file from start to finish that should be sufficient.

Comment: Ah.  I see your point.  I'll give that a shot.